# Adding a title attribute with jQuery, where the value comes from a .NET Dictionary (ASP.NET MVC 3)

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a Multi Select List generated by HTML.ListBoxFor. The select element has an id of '#listBox'

I want to add a title attribute to each option tag. The value of the title attribute comes from a `Dictionary<string,string>`.

I want to do the following

loop through option element of the selectlist and get the text of the option element

loop through each element of Dictionary

Where `dictionary.key == text` 
add a title attribute with the value of Dictionary.Value.

Comment: I haven't done jQuery for ages, so i'm pretty much stuck at the first hurdle, of even looping through the option elements of the selectlist

Comment: $('#yourSelect option').each(function(){..do stuff..});

Comment: @Doozer1979 You will not be able to do that, since you can't loop on your server-side type after you get text client-side with Jquery,since client-side only works after page is rendered. Is there some other way you can get those values from Option Element? Where do you get text from?

Comment: The text is the innerHtml of the option element

Comment: I guess i'll have to get the values into an regular javascript array

Comment: @Doozer1979 Exactly what I was going to suggest, take a look at this [Jquery Dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402180/does-jquery-support-dictionaries-key-value-collection)

Comment: You could always use ajax to return a json encoed array of your dictionary items, and then parse those in the `success: function(data)`, it will allow you to manipulate the elements before being inserted into the DOM, unlike what @user101609 said.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Yes that is correct, but why would you want do this if you already have your items in the View?

Comment: how are you sending the list to the view ? could you show your code for your ViewPage and the controller action that returns the view? Also why do u need to set a title attribute? the reason i ask is you could extend the DorpDownListFor helper method and do this server side. look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7536631/1279541)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post [Add attribute to select list option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285303/store-extra-value-per-item-in-drop-down-list/11285916#11285916). It allows you to put any attributes you want into the option items of a dropdown.